# Samsung Galaxy S3 not working after FACTORY RESET & HARD RESET

Tags: factory-reset, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. Everything was just fine a week ago, untill it started freezing like 10 times a day. I deleted the apps i recently installed but the phone kept on freezing. yesterday i used the factory reset. Now when i turn i get this window popped up: Android is upgrading. Optimizing app "x" of "Y". It stops upgrading in the last 9 apps. 
After this i Hard Reset the phone. Got however the same result. I tried there after flashing roms and using ADB.. but since my debugging is disabled it wont let me use the ADB SHELL command. I have searched now hours and hours for the solution, but i got no closer to the solution. please help me.

Hyun

Comment: How long did you wait making sure it "stopped in the last 9 apps"? It sometimes can take a while to generate the DEX files, especially for larger apps on slower devices. If you interrupt the upgrade process, it has to be repeated on the next start (at least for those left-over "last 9 apps").

Answer (score 1):

You can flash rom using Odin and you can download the stock rom zip from Samsung firmware or you can download any custom rom zip(if rooted) and flash it using Odin.